Launching EC2 Instances using Terraform resources aws_launch_template{} and aws_instance{} does not enable monitoring even though monitoring{} exists
I tried out the creation of EC2 Instances using aws_launch_template{} and aws_instance{} resources , but after doing that, the detailed monitoring does not activate and for some reason I get such result:

My launch template and EC2 Instance resource look like this:
resource "aws_launch_template" "name_lauch_template" {
  name                   = "main-launch-template"
  image_id               = "ami-0314c062c813a4aa0"
  update_default_version = true
  instance_type          = "t3.medium"
  ebs_optimized          = false
  key_name               = aws_key_pair.main.key_name

  monitoring {
    enabled = true
  }

  hibernation_options {
    configured = false
  }

  network_interfaces {
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    security_groups             = [ "${aws_security_group.main_sg.id}" ]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "main_instances" {
  count             = 5
  availability_zone = "eu-west-3a"

  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.name_lauch_template.id
  }
}

I have monitoring{} block defined and have monitoring enabled so why is it writing that it is disabled ? Has anyone else encountered this problem and know the solution ?

The Terraform version that I used is 1.9.4. The Terraform aws provider version that I used is 5.60.0.

Which AMI is that? Amazon Linux? Ubuntu? Are you using an instance profile?

Please verify if you are using the latest AWS terraform provider version. Monitoring has been available since v0.6.0...

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Yes, I am using the latest version. I am using 5.x AWS provider version.
